# how to load all recycler view items at once

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am making shopping app and I am listing user's cart in a recycler view then calculate total price inside `onBindViewHolder` but I have to scroll down to get price of all items.
can I make recycler view load all items at once or is there better solution to count total price?
by the way I tried putting the recycler view inside nester scroll view but did not work it show empty list

Comment: can you share what you have done already?

Comment: If you want to get the total price, calculate it when you get the data list.

Comment: Using `onBindViewHolder` to add up prices is a really bad idea and will lead to incorrect results due to recycling.  @GuanHongHuang is correct: just add up the prices in the data list.

Answer (score 0):

The point of a `RecyclerView` is to only create a few item views and reuse them, instead of creating a view for each item like a `ListView`. `onBindViewHolder` is where one of those item views (the `ViewHolder`) asks for the data it needs to display - it's a function about a specific item, not really where you'd do general code for the entire display.

But your `Adapter` is there to provide a view of your backing data - you have something like a list of all the items, and in `onBindViewHolder` you're given the `position` of one of them, and you pull out an item from your data list, right? Scrolling down is just displaying the data you already have, so you should do your calculation directly on that data source

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load everything. You already have a list that you're passing to your recycler view, all you need to do is to loop through that list and select the prices from that list and add it to a variable and when it's done you have the total price

Answer (score 0):

The main Problem that I understand according to your Question is that you want to Display all the items that are added by user on Cart and also you want to scroll down and add up all the prices and want to see whole price.

Okay, First of all why you are putting Recycler View in Scroll View? Recycler View is displaying all your items. Remove it. It is Wrong. Make a Recycler View. Send all data to Recycler View and it will display all your items selected by user in Cart Screen. After Recycler View you only give one text view that shows you total price.

If you want to ask logic ok total price. Also Comment down. Thanks.